# Linux boot from USB - grub, bios

Tags: boot, usb

I have an old PC that I started putting Linux distros on a long time ago and now I got it running one called Elementary OS. I'm trying to boot from a USB drive ISO, and it won't let me do it.

I've never dealt with grub before and I don't understand it. I've read some of the related answers on here and elsewhere like this http://blog.viktorpetersson.com/post/93191892924/how-to-boot-from-usb-with-grub2

But if I type initrd(hd1,0) then boot it gives me an error saying I have to load the kernel first.

Another answer said chainloader +1 but that also gives me an error.

I can get to the BIOS (Gateway) and select the USB drive but it always puts me right into grub. Am I stuck using Elementary OS forever?

Comment: How you set up the USB drive with ISO? Have you just copied it to a thumb drive?

Comment: "setup the USB drive " .. Is it that you are trying to make your usb drive bootable or something?